# How to disable address filtering in Contiki-NG cc2420 radio module?

Tags: contiki, texas-instruments, contiki-ng

When trying to disable address filtering by changing RADIO_PARAM_RX_MODE like below, cc2420 auto ack is not working and motes get duplicated packets.

```
radio_value_t radio_rx_mode;
NETSTACK_RADIO.get_value(RADIO_PARAM_RX_MODE, &radio_rx_mode);
radio_rx_mode &= ~RADIO_RX_MODE_ADDRESS_FILTER;
if(NETSTACK_RADIO.set_value(RADIO_PARAM_RX_MODE, radio_rx_mode) != RADIO_RESULT_OK) {
    LOG_WARN("radio does not support setting RADIO_PARAM_RX_MODE\n");
}else{
    LOG_INFO("turned of Address filtering.\n");
}
```

How to turn off just address filtering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is the correct way to disable the address recognition / filtering.

Regarding auto-ACK, the CC2420 datasheet says this:

> If `MDMCTRL0.AUTOACK` is enabled, an acknowledge frame is transmitted for  all incoming frames accepted by the address recognition with the acknowledge request flag set and a valid CRC. AUTOACK therefore does not make sense unless also `ADR_DECODE` and `AUTOCRC` are enabled.

This means that if you have address filtering disabled, you need to send software ACK.

Comment: enable software ack by defining CSMA_CONF_SEND_SOFT_ACK in project-conf.h of contiki-ng but when i count the acked packet getting 0?
for counting the packet i define LINK_STATS_CONF_PACKET_COUNTERS in project-conf.

Comment: The problem was the short time to get the acked packet and i change the CSMA_ACK_WAIT_TIME in csma.h file to fix this problem.